# Control flow with while loops and if statements

Tags: c, if-statement, while-loop

I'm having trouble understanding the control flow within a segment of my code. The code is written to take a startword (i.e cat) and an endword (i.e dog) change 1 letter of the original word at a time and reach the end word - checking against a dictionary of real words. If a non-real word is reached, i.e `cat --> dat`, it should break out of the loop and try changing a different letter.

```
while (strcmp (startword, endword) != FALSE)
    {      
    change_letter(startword, endword, i++);
    if ((check_dictionary(dictionary, startword)) == FALSE)
        {
            printf("%s --> ", startword);
            printf("Bad route\n");
            break;
        }
   if ((check_dictionary(dictionary, startword)) == TRUE)
        {
        printf("%s --> ", startword);
        }
    }
```

change_letter will just do `startword[i] = endword[i]`, where i is initialized at 0 (for the first letter, and moves through the letters  as i++ appears.

check dictionary compares the word against the dictionary, if the word is found a 1 is returned. (#define TRUE = 1, #define FALSE = 0).

Right now it will print (if using `cat and dog` as the words)

`cat --> dat --> Bad route` and thats all.

To my understanding it should never leave the top while loop whilst the two words are not equal.

Comment: Learn to use a debugger

Comment: Ensure that startword and endword are null terminating string

Comment: I'm using scanf which adds a null terminator

Comment: @squeamishossifrage That's true ,  but OP as used them as macro I think .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while (strcmp (startword, endword))
{      
    change_letter(startword, endword, i++);
    if (!check_dictionary(dictionary, startword))
    {
        printf("%s --> ", startword);
        printf("Bad route\n");
    }
    else (check_dictionary(dictionary, startword))
    {
        printf("%s --> ", startword);
    }
}
```

Modified your code a bit. Removed break, as it breaks control flow from loop and control is on the next statement after loop's `}`. That was your issue. Not sure if it works now, though, as it depends on your `check_dictionary` implementation.

Additionally, comparison `== TRUE` is useless. You can endlessly write `check_dictionary(dictionary, startword) == TRUE == TRUE == TRUE == TRUE`, the meaning will be all the same. Same as in while loop. It makes your code less understandable and is generally a bad practice.

After all, I removed second function call to make the function return value being evaluated only once.

Also, try to control your code readability by keeping same coding style (bracers!). It improves your code's readability.

Sorry for being boring.